DHCP clients losing current DNS configuration after DHCP server goes offline
We have TWO Domain Controllers, one with DHCP and DNS roles installed(DC1) and the other with just DNS(DC2).
For a while the scope options did NOT include a second DNS as an option but it's been about a month since I've fixed that. Our DHCP lease time is 8 days so there should've been ample time for an IP renewal to occur and the alternative DNS to have pushed down.
I've run a ipconfig /all on our DHCP clients and can see some have the updated IP configuration but not all of them.
I've manually set them and tested connectivity for each one individually and they performed just fine.
The problem occurs when DC1 goes offline and suddenly certain DHCP clients lose the alternative DNS(DC2), ultimately losing internet...
I don't understand why this is happening. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

welcome, please read carefully [ask]. we need more input from you. is the dhcp also the dns server? if yes then the answers is already known

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
